# Is 'verb + so + adjective' correct?

Tags: grammar

I've by chance learned the following sentence:
Why does the idea of progress loom so large in the modern world?
It confuses me a great deal,as I think that it should've been 'loom so largely'. Could you please tell me if the usage of 'verb + so + adjective' correct?

Comment: Your use of "large" as an adverb is okay. The adverb "largely" doesn't convey an adverbial meaning of "large" (as in "big" / "of great size"). Other examples of unsuffixed adverbs are "fast" (_Don't drive so fast_), "late" (_Don't Arrive late_) and "hard" (_They tried hard_)

Comment: Now I see, really appreciate your help.

Comment: This Q has been dealt with earlier. See previous posts about "-ly."

Comment: Possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might think that phrases like "ran so hard" and "to live so free" were such examples, but a dictionary would categorize such usages as adverbs.  For example,

**free (adverb)**

> 1. in a free way:
>      "The gate opened, and the animals ran free."
>      [Merriam Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/free)